# error with read.table and import on joined file

Tags: r

I have created a file joining 7 column txt header below:
 head(joined)

```
    Date....gpcp.......modens.....arp........had........gfdl........miroc......ich........ccc........ncc
1  1981-01-01 0.234878    0.469833   0.277215   0.427785   0.391026     1.02363   0.141564   0.613363   0.414251 
2  1981-02-01 0.410771    0.702776    1.09794   0.710179   0.389277     1.26023   0.386144   0.676518   0.399144
```

when I try to read it i am having an error message I have difficulties solving and expect as usual hints to fix it.

```
> data1<-read.table(joined, header=T, sep=" ", row.names=1)
    Error in read.table(joined, header = T, sep = " ", row.names = 1) : 
      'file' must be a character string or connection
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `text=joined`?

Comment: I created the joined file using the command:

Comment: I used the command line in linux: paste gpcp.txt modens.txt ........> joined

Comment: if the filename is `joined` then put quotes around it like so `"joined"` in the `read.table` function

Comment: I used read.csv to read the file create with paste and the joined file should in the working directory or just loaded by R. I used write.table

Comment: > data1<-read.table("joined", header=T, sep=" ", row.names=1)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'joined': No such file or directory
it looks it can't this way locate the file

Comment: what values do you get when you run `getwd()` in R and `pwd` in linux shell?

Comment: I get my working directory /Users/sarr

Comment: can get the file now. With import function (package openair) I am having the error message can't find variable Date: > mydata<-openair("joinded", date="Date", header=T, sep=" ", row.name=1) don't know why

Comment: I managed to create a file wusing rbind: datall.txt<-cbind(date, gpcp, modens, arp, miroc, gfdl, had, ccc, ncc, ich)

Comment: I managed to create a file using rbind:datall.txt<-cbind(date, gpcp, modens, arp, miroc, gfdl, had, ccc, ncc, ich)                                                                                                                             date      gpcp   modens      arp    miroc      gfdl      had      ccc      ncc      ich
1   1981-01-01 0.2348780 0.469833 0.277215 1.023630 0.3910260 0.427785 0.613363 0.414251 0.141564

Comment: I can't locate where the file is stored